# Circe list deserialization with best-attempt and error reporting

Tags: json, scala, circe, argonaut

I'm using Circe to deserialize json containing a list. Sometimes a few items in the json list are corrupted, and that causes the entire deserialization to fail. Instead, I want Circe to make a best attempt, and to return a list of all the successfully deserialized list items, together with a list of errors for the corrupted items. How is this best done in Circe?

Specifically, lets say I'm trying to deserialize this:

```
val json = """{ "params": {
  "playlist": {
      "name": "Sample Playlist",
      "items": [
        {
          "clipId":"xyz", 
          "name":"abc",
          "properties": {
            "cat": "siamese",
            "dog": "spaniel"            
          }
        },
        {
          "clipId":"pqr", 
          "name":"def",
          "properties": {
            "cat": "tabby",
            "dog": "terrier"
          }
        } 
      ]
   }
}}"""
```

I'm doing this with:

```
import io.circe.Decoder, io.circe.generic.auto._
import scala.util._   

case class Clip(clipId: String, name: String, dog: String)
implicit val decodeClip: Decoder[Clip] = Decoder.instance { c =>
    for {
      id <- c.get[String]("clipId")
      name <- c.get[String]("name")
      dog <- c.downField("properties").get[String]("dog")
    } yield {
      Clip(id, name, dog)
    }
}

val decodeClipsParam = Decoder[List[Clip]].prepare(
  _.downField("params").downField("playlist").downField("items")
)

def deserializedThing(theJson: String) = io.circe.parser.decode(theJson)(decodeClipsParam)
```

It works fine, and correctly deserializes:

```
scala> deserializedThing(json)
res1: Either[io.circe.Error,List[circeLab.circeLab.Clip]] = Right(List(Clip(xyz,abc,spaniel), Clip(pqr,def,terrier)))
```

But if I now corrupt one single item of the json list (by changing one of the `"dog"` keys to `"doggg"` say), then the entire deserialization fails - it doesn't give me the list of uncorrupted `Clip` items, it just tells me that it failed.

So instead of deserializing into `List[Clip]` I'd like to deserialize into `List[Try[Clip]]`, where each item is either like `Success(Clip(xyz,abc,spaniel))`, or `Failure(ErrorDescriptionForThatItem)`.

I was able to achieve this in Argonaut (using some rather ugly code), but can't figure out the syntax in Circe. What's the best way to achieve this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so this solution works:

```
import io.circe.{Json, Decoder}
import io.circe.parser.parse 
import scala.util.{Try, Success, Failure} 

// Throw this exception if the list of items can't even be retrieved
case class ParseException(msg: String) extends Exception(msg) 

case class Clip(clipId: String, name: String, dog: String)
// This is the decoder that tries to decode an individual item
implicit val decodeClip: Decoder[Clip] = Decoder.instance { c =>
    for {
      id <- c.get[String]("clipId")
      name <- c.get[String]("name")
      dog <- c.downField("properties").get[String]("dog")
    } yield {
      Clip(id, name, dog)
    }
}


// Turn a string into a json doc
def jsonDoc(str: String) = parse(str).getOrElse(Json.Null)

// Attempt to retrieve the list of json objects appearing in "items"
def getListOfItemsAsJsonObjects(doc: Json): Try[List[Json]] = doc.hcursor.downField("params").downField("playlist").downField("items").focus match {
  case None => Failure(ParseException("Couldn't get items"))
  case Some(obj) => obj.asArray match {
    case None => Failure(ParseException("Couldn't turn to array"))
    case Some(arr) => Success(arr.toList)
  }
}


// Finally, map each json object from Items to a Try[Clip], so individual corrupted items don't affect others.
def tryListOfTries(str: String) = getListOfItemsAsJsonObjects(jsonDoc(str)).map(ok => ok.map(_.as[Clip].toTry))
```

If there are no corruptions in the json string, then `tryListOfTries(json)` will return this:

```
Success(List(Success(Clip(xyz,abc,spaniel)), Success(Clip(pqr,def,terrier))))
```

If you corrupt an individual `item` you'll get something like this, with the other `items` decoded ok:

```
Success(List(Failure(DecodingFailure(Attempt to decode value on failed cursor, List(DownField(dog), DownField(properties)))), Success(Clip(pqr,def,terrier))))
```

And if you corrupt something at a higher level so it can't even retrieve the `items` array, then you'll get a `Failure` at the top level:

```
Failure(ParseException: Couldn't get items)
```

Not sure whether there's a more idiomatic solution, but I couldn't find one so I hope this helps someone.